# stop specfic process in python ProcessPoolExecutor or shared state btw them

Tags: multiprocessing, python-3.6, python-multiprocessing

This is my code

```
def long_stage_task(node, deployment_folder_name, stage_s3_bucket):
      global workers
      logging.info("starting....")
      work = StageOS(node, deployment_folder_name, stage_s3_bucket)--> class
      work.stagestart()--> class method
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
executor.submit(long_stage_task, i, deployment_folder_name, stage_s3_bucket)
```

Now how can i stop a particular process/pid. 
Is there any way to pass globals or shared state btw them, i don't see any thing in the doc.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Answer (score 0):

You could pass to the workers a list of [Events](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event) and set them when you want the worker to stop. This implies your `long_stage_task` function periodically checks its own Event.

If what you are after is stopping a task which is taking too long, you can take a look at [pebble](https://pypi.org/project/Pebble/). It allows to set timeouts to function calls as well as to cancel ongoing tasks.